# Why "Designtime Attributes" doesn't work?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, gui-designer, designtime-attributes

### Background

Google added nice "[**Designtime Attributes**](http://tools.android.com/tips/layout-designtime-attributes)" (found about it from [**here**](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/tools-attributes)) to be used only for UI-designer mode, so, for example, if you wish to show text on a textView (or EditText) just there (to help you understand how it looks like), you can just add:

```
    <EditText 
        tools:text="John Doe"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

example from Google:

[image]

In fact, this should work for **any** attribute you can already use. Not sure if there are any limitations, but it's very cool.

### The problem

Now, when I do this in Eclipse (just a simple textView with the "tools:text" attribute), together with the latest ADT & SDK (22.3.0.v201310242005-887826) , it just doesn't work. It just doesn't do anything.

### The question

Is it possible this feature works only for the new IDE (android studio) ? If so, how could it be? Shouldn't Google add each android-development feature to the ADT too?

Also, how come on some websites it's called "Designtime Layout Attributes" and on some it's just "Designtime Attributes" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, It seems this is planned for ADT (found from [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=46186)) :

> Q:I see this is in Android Studio...   Any plans for this to come to
>   Eclipse/ADT?
>
> A:Yes, we'll port it to ADT. No ETA yet.